# Convert chip from CANFD or SPI signal to Ether packet

Tags: ethernet

I have to convert CANFD or SPI signal to Ether packet.
Are there any good solution chip?
If exist, how many bitrate does it have?

My product has CANFD interface and SPI interface, no ethernet interface, but customer requests Ethernet output.

Normally the product use CANFD, but I couldn’t discover convert chip from CANFD to ether packet.
So SPI is also acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Which Microcontroller are you using then?

It is possible to convert CAN-FD data into Ethernet data very easily but for that you would require a Microcontroller with an Ethernet Interface to begin with. Otherwise, it is not possible :-)

After you have the right microcontroller with Ethernet & CAN-FD Interfaces, the solutions in Software would be different depending on the fact whether you are using an AUTOSAR stack from a Vendor like Vektor, Elektrobit etc. or you are having a bare-metal implementation.

In case you are using AUTOSAR, then you can just activate 2 callbacks(Tx+Rx) in the CAN driver and in the implementation of the callbacks copy the CAN-FD data into an array *'UDP_Payload[1472]'* using a particular format so that the CAN-FD messages can be reconstructed at the end of the receiver.

In a separate runnable mapped to a cyclic task, you can make a call to the function *'LdCom_Transmit(id, &UDP_Payload[0])'* to transmit the Ethernet packet out on the wire! Hope that helps :)